# Generating CSR for multi-domain

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

How to generate CSR for mult-domain.

I found that generating CSR for single domain is as below:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

But how do I generate CSR multi-domain

Comment: Probably more for ServerFault: voted to move.

Comment: The last paragraph of Bruno's answer is best answer IMHO - don't worry about it, just specify the primary or a single domain in the CSR, and add the other domains later when you are generating the certificate.  Works for me with ssls.com

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For an X.509 certificate to support multiple domains, it must use multiple Subject Alternative Name DNS entries, according to [RFC 2818 (HTTP over TLS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (or RFC 6125):

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.
>
> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.)

As described in [this document](http://www.crsr.net/Notes/SSL.html) (except I would use `-des3` too for the `genrsa` command, to protect the private key):

- Make a copy your initial `openssl.cnf` file (the original is probably somewhere under `/etc` on Linux).
- Edit it to add `req_extensions = v3_req` in the `[ req ]` section.
- Edit it to add `subjectAltName=DNS:www.example.com,DNS:www.other-example.com` (one `DNS:` entry per host name you require) in the `[ v3_req ]` section.
- Make OpenSSL use that configuration file. Call it with `OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/your/openssl.cnf openssl req ...`

This being said, I wouldn't worry too much about setting any extension in the CSR. Any good CA should ignore whatever you've set in the CSR and only set whatever they have actually verified when issuing the actual certificate. They'll happily replace any RDN in your Subject DN (e.g. Country, Organization, ...) as well as any extension (SAN or Key Usage). Firstly, if they let any extension as requested in the CSR by the applicant, this would be a security risk, since some applicants could really get anything. Secondly, that's how they make extra money, by charging you for setting a few bits here and there (e.g. code signing extension): they'll make sure that you only get what you've paid for in your certificate. I understand, though, that you may want to put all the names you request in your CSR, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks most for the comment about how it is not important to specify all the domain names you are planning to secure in the CSR.  I was getting hung up on this, and then took that advice and sure enough, ssls.com had a mechanism to add additional domains after importing the CSR.